# Converting DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in Perl

Tags: html, forms, perl, date

I am entering a date using a html form in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I want to convert this in perl to YYYY-MM-DD so that I can enter it into a MySQL database.

I am unsure of how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried do this however, when I enter the record, the date appears at 0000-00-00 in my Database.

Below is my PERL code:

```
    #!/xampp/perl/bin/perl  -w

    require "dbfunc.pl";
    use CGI qw/:standard/;
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
    $dbh    = getConnection();

    $Btable  = "booking";
    $CDtable = "carddetails";
    $Stable = "seats";
    $Rtable = "route";

    $CustomerID = param("CustomerID");
    $Rid = param("Rid");

    my $Tdate = param("Tdate");
    $Tdate =~ s/(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})/\3\2\1/;

    $Aticket = param("Aticket");
    $Cticket = param("Cticket");
    $tickettotal = $Aticket + $Cticket;

    $Cname = param("Cname");
    $Ctype= param("Ctype");
    $Noc = param("Noc");
    $Scode = param("Scode");
    $Edate = param("Edate");

    #Booking Refrence Generator
    my @chars = ("A".."Z", "a".."z", "1".."9");
    my $BookingReference;
    $BookingReference .= $chars[rand @chars] for 1..10;

    sub selectTable {
     $statement = shift (@_);

     ## select data from a table and output as an HTML table
     ## Prepare and Execute an SQL select statement
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
    $sth->execute();

     ## Get the data as an array of arrays and output by position
    while (@ary = $sth->fetchrow_array) {


    if ($Rid == 1) {
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 2){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 3){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 4){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 5){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 6){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 7){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 8){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
    if ($Aticket == 0){
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
    }
    if ($Rid == 9){
    $tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
    $tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
    }
if ($Aticket == 0){
$tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
}
if ($Rid == 10){
$tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
$tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
}
if ($Aticket == 0){
$tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
}`enter code here`
if ($Rid == 11){
$tot1 = $Aticket * $ary[5];
$tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[6];
}
if ($Aticket == 0){
$tot2 = $Cticket * $ary[5]
}


    print qq!

<td>$ary[4]</td>                                             
  </tr>\n!;

}
   print "</table>\n";
}


sub insertTable {
 $statement = shift (@_);
 $dbh->do($statement);
}  # sub
print header;
print start_html("Booking Information");

print qq!
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <div id="cssmenu">
   <ul>
        <li> <a href="http://localhost/webprog/Home.pl"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/webprog/RouteBooking.pl"><span>Booking</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/webprog/liveroute.pl"><span>Timetables</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="http://localhost/webprog/ContactUs.pl"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Titlebar">
      <header>&nbsp; Route Availbility</header>
    </div>
    <div id="Sidebar"> </div>

    !;



selectTable("SELECT * FROM $Rtable WHERE RouteID='".$Rid."'");

#selectTable("SELECT * FROM $Stable WHERE RouteID='".$Rid."' AND Date='".$Tdate."'");

$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Btable(CustomerID,BookingReference,Date,RouteID,TotalPassengersBooked,AdultTickets, ChildTickets) VALUES ('".$CustomerID."', '".$BookingReference."', '".$Tdate."' , '".$Rid."', '".$tickettotal."', '".$Aticket."', '".$Cticket."')");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $CDtable(CustomerID,NameOnCard,CardType,NumberOnCard,SecruityCode,Expirydate) VALUES ('".$CustomerID."', '".$Cname."','".$Ctype."','".$Noc."','".$Scode."','".$Edate."')");
$Tdate =~ s/-//gi;
$dateandrid = $Tdate . $Rid;
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(RouteAndDate,Date,RouteID) VALUES ('$dateandrid','$Tdate','$Rid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(RouteAndDate,Date,RouteID) VALUES ('$dateandrid','$Tdate','$Rid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-'$tickettotal'");

print qq!  <p>Your booking details are: <br>

 <br> <p>Membership ID: $CustomerID <br>
 <br> <p>Route ID: $Rid <br>
 <br> <p>Travel Date: $Tdate : YYYY-MM-DD <BR>
 <br> <p>Total tickets purchased: $tickettotal <br>
 <br> <p>Consisting off $Aticket adult tickets and $Cticket child tickets <br>!;

 $total = $tot1 + $tot2;
 print qq! Total Price is $total pounds <br>!; 

 print qq!

 <br>Please make note of your Booking Refrence as it is required to cancel your booking
 <br>

 <br> Your Booking Reference Is - $BookingReference <br>
 <br> Right click Download File and select save file as to download
<br> <br>
 !;

print qq! <a href="report.txt">Download File</a>!;


my $filename = 'report.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "Membership ID:  $CustomerID\n"; 
print $fh "RouteID:  $Rid\n";
print $fh "Travel Date:  $Tdate\n";
print $fh "Total Tickets Purchased:  $tickettotal\n";
print $fh "Consisting off  $Aticket adult tickets and  $Cticket child tickets\n";
print $fh "Total price is $total pounds\n";
print $fh "Please make note of your booking reference as it required to cancel your booking if you wish to do so\n";
print $fh "\n";
print $fh "Your Booking Reference is:  $BookingReference";
close $fh;
```

HTML CODE in PERL file:

```
#!/xampp/perl/bin/perl  -w

require "dbfunc.pl";
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

print header;
print start_html("Route Booking");


print_html_head_section();

print qq!
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/webprog/Home.pl"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/webprog/RouteBooking.pl"><span>Booking</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/webprog/liveroute.pl"><span>Timetables</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/webprog/ContactUs.pl"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="http://localhost/webprog/Login.html"><span>Employee Login</span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Titlebar">
      <header>&nbsp; Booking</header>
    </div>
    <div id="Sidebar"> <img src="logo.jpg" alt="WebBus" style=width:225px;height:225px></div>


    !;

print "<h1> Route Selection</h1>";

print qq!<form method="POST" name="MyForm" onsubmit="return f2()" action="RouteBookingInsert.pl"><br />!;

print qq!<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CustomerID: <input type="text",  name="CustomerID", id="CustomerID"  size=20><br>! ;

print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Route ID: <select name="Rid">  

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
</select><br>!;

print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date of travel: <input type="text", id="Tdate" , name="Tdate" size=20> <br>! ;

print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of Adult Tickets: <select name="Aticket">  
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select><br>!;

print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of Child Tickets: <select name="Cticket">  
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select><br>!;
sub someJS {

print  "<button type='button' onclick='return f2()'>Try it</button> \n";
}


sub print_html_head_section {
    print "<head>\n";
    print "<script src='RouteBookingValidation.js'    type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
    print "</head>\n";
}
print qq! <br>!;

print "<h1>Card Details</h1>\n";

print qq!<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name On Card: <input type="text", id="Cname" , name="Cname" size=20> <br> !; 
print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Card Type: <select name="Ctype">  

<option value="Visa">Visa</option>
<option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
<option value="Amex">Amex</option>
<option value="Solo">Solo</option>
</select><br>!;

print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number On Card:<input type="text", id="Noc" , name="Noc" size=20> <br>! ;
print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Secruity Code: <input type="text", id="Scode" , name="Scode" size=20> <br>! ;
print qq! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Expiry Date: <input type="text", name="Edate" , id="Edate" size=20> <br>! ;

print qq!<br> !;


print qq!<br /><input type="submit" value="Book" style="width:50px"/>\n</form><br />!;

print end_html;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you really going to use this mess of a code for getting real credit card data from your customers?! *Please* don't do so! CGI.pm is kind of outdated, at least really old. If you need to get it done on your own, look at `DBIx::Class` and a modern Web framework like Dancer2 oder Catalyst. Maybe even stick to a shop software off the shelf. You **will** have critical security issues in your code when passing form input to the DB with CGI.pm and plain SQL! You have been warned.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, This is for a university project and don't have to include a payment method, It's just there for show

Comment: Even if it is _just an university project_ you should do it right and learn modern perl. `use strict;` and `use warnings;` ... prepared SQL statements with placeholders ... there are many issues with your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code from your script:

```
my $Tdate = param("Tdate");
$Tdate =~ s/(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})/\3\2\1/;
```

will turn:

```
18/04/2015
```

into:

```
4/20/01815
```

Which is probably not what you want and which MySQL really ought to reject outright but instead it stores it as the null date.

You probably want something like this:

```
$Tdate =~ s{^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$}{$3-$2-$1};
```

Which will work if the user supplies a date in exactly the format you expect.  You really ought to add some validation logic to confirm that the date submitted was a valid format and had valid values for day, month and year.  Consider using a module like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) or [DateManip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip).

Also in the web page you might like to consider using something like this [date entry widget](http://grantm.github.io/jquery-datetextentry/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to parse data from CSV and insert into Postgres SQL using Perl. I come added this piece of code and it all works for me

`my $date = '31/01/2019';
 $date =~ m /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/;
 my $fdate = "$3-$2-$1";
 print $fdate . "\n";`

This one-liner will do the job as well

`$date = '31/01/2019';
 $date =~ s /(^\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}$)/$3-$2-$1/;`

Hope that will be helpful.